# LRU Cache in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, cache

This is a simple and robust LRUCache implementation using doubly linked list and unordered map. It supports `.get()`, `.put()`, and `.has()` operations in constant time.

I want to know if my code conforms to the best practices. Any suggestions or feedback are appreciated!

```
#pragma once

#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace cache {

template <typename KeyType,
        typename ValueType,
        typename KeyHash = std::hash<KeyType>,
        typename KeyEqual = std::equal_to<KeyType>>
class LRUCache {
private:
    using KeyValuePair = std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>;
    using ListIterator = typename std::list<KeyValuePair>::iterator;

    const size_t maxSize_;
    std::unordered_map<KeyType, ListIterator> hashmap_;
    std::list<KeyValuePair> itemsList_;

    void promoteItemWithKey(const KeyType& key)
    {
        ListIterator keyIterator = hashmap_[key];
        if (std::next(keyIterator) == itemsList_.end()) {
            return;
        }
        std::iter_swap(keyIterator, std::next(keyIterator));
        hashmap_[key] = std::next(keyIterator);
        hashmap_[keyIterator->first] = keyIterator;
    }

    void removeItemWithKey(const KeyType& key)
    {
        itemsList_.erase(hashmap_[key]);
        hashmap_.erase(key);
    }

public:
    LRUCache(size_t maxSize)
        : maxSize_(maxSize) {};

    bool has(const KeyType& key) const
    {
        return hashmap_.find(key) != hashmap_.end();
    }

    ValueType get(const KeyType& key)
    {
        if (!this->has(key))
            throw std::range_error("The key doesn't exist in the cache.");
        this->promoteItemWithKey(key);
        return hashmap_[key]->second;
    }

    void put(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& value)
    {
        if (this->has(key)) {
            this->removeItemWithKey(key);
        }

        if (itemsList_.size() == maxSize_) {
            hashmap_.erase(itemsList_.begin()->first);
            itemsList_.pop_front();
        }
        itemsList_.emplace_back(std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>(key, value));
        hashmap_[key] = std::next(itemsList_.end(), -1);
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return itemsList_.size();
    }

    size_t capacity() const noexcept
    {
        return maxSize_;
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Do you have some tests, or at least a simple `main()` that shows this class in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Headers

We're missing some headers.  I'm guessing that your platform happens to include these as a side-effect of including `<list>` and `<unordered_map>`, but that's not a portable assumption.

```
#include <algorithm>            // for std::iter_swap
#include <cstddef>              // for std::size_t
#include <functional>           // for std::equal_to and std::hash
#include <iterator>             // for std::next
#include <stdexcept>            // for std::range_error
#include <utility>              // for std::pair
```

## Size member

We've consistently misspelt `std::size_t` (as just `size_t`).  Again, another portability problem.

We might want to check that we are not given a zero size; doing so will break the code's assumptions in `put()`.  We could test and throw, or we could use `std::min` to ensure it's at least 1, for example.

The accessor `capacity()` is fairly pointless - we could simply make the `maxSize_` member public (which is safe, because it's declared `const`).

## Strange promotion isn't LRU

Despite the name, this cache doesn't discard the **least-recently** used item to make space, as `promoteItemWithKey` only swaps the used item with the next one in the list.  True LRU means moving the accessed item to the end of the queue; I think you might be able to use the list's `splice()` method to achieve this more efficiently than `std::rotate`.

## Unnecessary explicit `this`

The redundant `this->` dereference can make code harder to read:

> ```
>     if (this->has(key)) {
>         this->removeItemWithKey(key);
>     }
> ```

It's rare that we need to explicitly write `this->` (usually only if we have name conflicts, or call a non-dependent template function), and we can write with much less clutter:

```
    if (has(key)) {
        removeItemWithKey(key);
    }
```

That said, I would prefer us to directly overwrite (and promote) the found element, rather than removing it and constructing a new one - that saves on memory allocation.  In fact, the same applies when removing a stale item to insert a new one -

## Unnecessary construction

Here, we have an unwieldy constructor that we don't need:

> ```
>     itemsList_.emplace_back(std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>(key, value));
> ```

The point of `emplace_back()` is to call the constructor for us:

```
    itemsList_.emplace_back(key, value);
```

## Consider passing by value

If we `put()` with an rvalue for `value`, it's copied unnecessarily.  It's probably better to push any copying to the caller (which may be able to elide it), and then `std::move` the value:

```
void put(const KeyType& key, ValueType value)
{
    // ...
    itemsList_.emplace_back(key, std::move(value));
```